# How to extract this element whose mother contains a specific text?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract a particular `<div class="list-holder"> .. </div>` which are in the same class as `<div class="heading-block"> ... </div>` which contains `<strong class="title">Dictionary browser</strong>`. Could you please elaborate on how to do so?

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.thefreedictionary.com/!'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
r = session.get(url, headers = headers) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS selectior `*:has(strong:contains("Dictionary browser")) ~ div.list-holder` to select your element:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.thefreedictionary.com/!'

soup = BeautifulSoup( requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser' )
list_holder = soup.select_one('*:has(strong:contains("Dictionary browser")) ~ div.list-holder')

print(list_holder.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<div class="list-holder">
 <ul>
  <li>
   ▲
  </li>
  <li class="current">
   !
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="!Kung">
    !Kung
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="(c)">
    (c)
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href=".+.+.">
    . . .
   </a>
  </li>

...and so on.
```

---

Or, if you don't prefer CSS selectors:

```
list_holder = soup.find('strong', text="Dictionary browser").find_next('div', class_="list-holder")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I have asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63572339/how-to-extract-all-the-class-a-after-a-specific-element) about a refined extraction. I hope that you can have a look at it.