# How to extract all the class "a" after a specific element?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract all the element `a` inside a class whose text is `Full browser` with

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.freethesaurus.com/great+adductor+muscle'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

main = soup.select('*:has(strong:contains("Full browser")) ~ div.list-holder a')
list_holder = [x['href'] for x in main]

print(list_holder)
```

Could you please elaborate on how to select such `a` that appear after the element `<li class="current">...</li>`? Such `a` inside `<li class="current">...</li>` are also excluded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select all `<a>` tags after `<li class="current">` you can select all `<li>` and then check for previous sibling with `.find_previous_sibling()` method:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.freethesaurus.com/great+adductor+muscle'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for li in soup.select('div.heading-block:contains("Full browser") + div li:has(a)'):
    if li.find_previous_sibling('li', class_='current'):
        print('{:<45} {}'.format(li.a.text, li.a['href']))
```

Prints:

```
Great Adirondack Birding Celebration          //acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Great+Adirondack+Birding+Celebration
Great Adirondack Tool Co.                     //acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Great+Adirondack+Tool+Co.
Great Adventure                               //acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Great+Adventure
Great Affordable Accommodation New Zealand    //acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Great+Affordable+Accommodation+New+Zealand
Great African Rift Valley                     //www.thefreedictionary.com/Great+African+Rift+Valley
Great African Rift Valley                     //encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Great+African+Rift+Valley
Great Alaskan Accounting People               //acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Great+Alaskan+Accounting+People
Great albatross                               //www.thefreedictionary.com/Great+albatross
Great Alfold                                  //www.thefreedictionary.com/Great+Alfold
Great Alfold                                  //encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Great+Alfold
Great Alföld                                  //www.thefreedictionary.com/Great+Alf%c3%b6ld
Great Alföld                                  //encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Great+Alf%c3%b6ld
Great Allegheny Passage                       //acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Great+Allegheny+Passage
Great Aloha Run                               //acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Great+Aloha+Run
Great Altai                                   //www.thefreedictionary.com/Great+Altai
great alveolar cells                          //medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/great+alveolar+cells
Great America                                 //acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Great+America
Great America Leasing Corporation             //acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Great+America+Leasing+Corporation
Great American Adventure Club                 //acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Great+American+Adventure+Club
Great American Aran Afghan                    //acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Great+American+Aran+Afghan
Great American Aran Afghan Along              //acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Great+American+Aran+Afghan+Along
Great American Backyard Campout               //acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Great+American+Backyard+Campout
Great American Bake Sale                      //acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Great+American+Bake+Sale
Great American Ball Park                      //acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Great+American+Ball+Park
Great American Ballpark                       //acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Great+American+Ballpark
Great American Baseball League                //acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Great+American+Baseball+League
Great American Bash                           //acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Great+American+Bash
Great American Beer Festival                  //acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Great+American+Beer+Festival
Great American Bike Race                      //acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Great+American+Bike+Race
Great American Brass Band Festival            //encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Great+American+Brass+Band+Festival
```